# Save edited XML Document to any location?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, c#-4.0

In the below C# WPF code snippet, I want to load an XML document, edit the document, and save the output to a user designated location.  I can use the `XmlDocument.Save` method to save to a pre-defined location, but how can I allow the user to save to any location like when choosing 'SaveAs'?

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\OriginalFile.xml");
doc.Save("File.xml");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622854/how-do-i-show-a-save-as-dialog-in-wpf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the code below; be aware that the UAC if the user select some system folder.

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog.Filter = "Xml (*.xml)|*.xml";
if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog().Value)
{
    doc.Save(saveFileDialog.FileName);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773.aspx). Sample from the article:

```
Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
dlg.FileName = "Document"; 
dlg.DefaultExt = ".xml";
dlg.Filter = "Xml documents (.xml)|*.xml"; // Filter files by extension 

Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
if (result == true)
{
    // Save document 
    string filename = dlg.FileName;
}
```