# Exporting a .txt, no overwrite warning appears

Tags: c#, wpf

When executing the following code, I would expect a warning pop up dialog, which will ask if I am sure I would like to overwrite the file, but no pop up appears. Does anyone know a simple way to implement it? Without having to create my own custom window

XAML:

```
 <Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="name"  Text="hi" />
    <Button x:Name="create_File" Click="create_File_Click" Content="make the notepad" Width="auto"/>
  </Grid>
```

c#:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

 public void createFile()
    {

     string text_line = string.Empty;
     string exportfile_name = "C:\\" + name.Text + ".txt";

     System.IO.StreamWriter objExport;
     objExport = new System.IO.StreamWriter(exportfile_name);

     string[] TestLines = new string[2];
                TestLines[0] = "****TEST*****";
                TestLines[1] = "successful";


                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    text_line = text_line + TestLines[i] + "\r\n";
                    objExport.WriteLine(TestLines[i]);

                }
              objExport.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Wrote File");

  }
  private void create_File_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        createFile();
    }
}
```

***UPDATE***

I was not using SaveFileDialog, Now I am and it works just how I would expect it too... thanks for the answers, here is what I have now:

```
 public void createFile()
    {
        string text_line = string.Empty;
        string export_filename = name.Text;


        Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.FileName = export_filename; // Default file name
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".text"; // Default file extension
        dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"; // Filter files by extension

        // Show save file dialog box
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();


        // save file
        System.IO.StreamWriter objExport;
        objExport = new System.IO.StreamWriter(dlg.FileName);

        string[] TestLines = new string[2];
        TestLines[0] = "****TEST*****";
        TestLines[1] = "successful";



        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            text_line = text_line + TestLines[i] + "\r\n";
            objExport.WriteLine(TestLines[i]);

        }
        objExport.Close();


    }


    private void create_File_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        createFile();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why would you expect a confirmation dialog to appear? You need to handle that logic yourself... also, you need to wrap your stream in a `using` block

Comment: Why would you expect that? You are writing to a file directly with a `StreamWriter`, which is just a class not a UI element. The `SaveFileDialog` will ask for confirmation when selecting an existing file, but for the `StreamWriter` this makes no sense at all (otherwise applications without UI could never make use of the `StreamWriter`).

Comment: @2 above, hmm okay well thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking the user whether the file should be overwritten is usually done *when the file path is chosen*, not when the file is actually written.

If you let the user choose the path using a [SaveFileDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5622854/87698), the [OverwritePrompt property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.savefiledialog.overwriteprompt(v=vs.110).aspx) is set to `true` by default, resulting in the confirmation dialog you desire.

If you don't want to use the SaveFileDialog, you can use a `MessageBox` with the [MessageBoxButtons.YesNo option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10414323/87698).

Answer (score 2):

1) Check if the File exists ([File.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx))

2) If it does, display a MessageBox ([MessageBox.Show](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598690.aspx)) with yes and no options.

3) Check if the user clicked yes, and only then execute the rest of your code

Comment: @thanks for giving me a way to do it with the method I was using, but the SaveFileDialog makes more sense, just didn't know about it

Answer (score 1):

```
DialogResult dialogResult = File.Exists(exportfile_name)
    ? MessageBox.Show(null, "Sure?", "Some Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) 
    : DialogResult.Yes;

if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    // save file
}
```