# Save Screenshot to specified directory when a button is clicked

Tags: c#, windows, screenshot

I am looking to make a small windows utility that will let the user browse to a file directory. Is there a good C# method (Windows) to execute this?

Comment: Why not use openFileDialog?

Comment: A file or a directory? wpf or forms?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622854/how-do-i-show-a-save-as-dialog-in-wpf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you configure an OpenFileDialog to select folders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059/how-do-you-configure-an-openfiledialog-to-select-folders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using WinForms, you want FolderBrowserDialog.

See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx